# How to set availability property of an event to be added in iphone calendar

Tags: ios4

I am using [event setAvailability:EKEventAvailabilityTentative]; to add availability property for an event but when fetching for event either it is free or busy or tentative I M getting -1 value for [event availability]; on every event.Am I not setting the property correctly or not fetching the property correctly?Please help